# Redis keyspace notification on event using regular expressions

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to generate expire event on redis keys which matches the provided pattern. I am using redis in node js.

I have tried using redis psubscribe using pattern but it is not solving my problem.

```
var redisClient = redis.createClient('redis://redis')
redisClient.config('set', 'notify-keyspace-events', 'KEA')
redisClient.psubscribe('__keyevent@0__:expired', '.*:timer')

redisClient.on('message', function (channel, key) { 
        console.log(`key ${key} channel ${channel}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is that when the redisClient object leaves its scope the object is disposed. I was facing the same issue in .Net but then I realized that my object was disposed some how that's why It could not invoke an event. If you can share the code snippet,we solve this problem.

But for now If you try this patch it will help.

```
var redisClient = redis.createClient('redis://redis')
```

declare this object globally and it will work.